# To get top three names of students with marks in each subject from 2 tables in oracle db from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have two tables: 
 **1)** Student with name and roll number
 **2)** Table with roll number, subject and marks.

I want to get the output such that it will show me the top 3 students in each subject with names.

Script of table which can be used is:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT ( ROLL_NO INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (1,'NIKHIL');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (2,'VARUN');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (3,'NISHANT');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (4,'VISHAL');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (5,'GOURAV');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (6,'HEMANT');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (7,'SHUBHAM');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (8,'DHAWAN');
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (9,'GAUTAM');


CREATE TABLE MARKS ( ROLL_NO INT, SUBJECT VARCHAR(20), MARKS INT);
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('1','MATHS','92');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('1','SCIENCE','80');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('1','ENGLISH','98');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('1','HINDI','81');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('2','MATHS','89');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('2','SCIENCE','100');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('2','ENGLISH','81');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('2','HINDI','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('3','MATHS','98');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('3','SCIENCE','92');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('3','ENGLISH','88');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('3','HINDI','83');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('4','MATHS','88');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('4','SCIENCE','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('4','ENGLISH','85');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('4','HINDI','97');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('5','MATHS','94');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('5','SCIENCE','90');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('5','ENGLISH','97');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('5','HINDI','89');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('6','MATHS','89');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('6','SCIENCE','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('6','ENGLISH','84');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('6','HINDI','85');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('7','MATHS','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('7','SCIENCE','100');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('7','ENGLISH','92');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('7','HINDI','98');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('8','MATHS','99');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('8','SCIENCE','91');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('8','ENGLISH','86');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('8','HINDI','82');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('9','MATHS','100');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('9','SCIENCE','95');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('9','ENGLISH','81');
INSERT INTO MARKS VALUES('9','HINDI','81');
```

[**Run It Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e97bb4)

Thanks in advance for helping
I need to run it on oracle

Comment: its not home work or project, i was asked this question by someone yesterday and i was finding a way to get answer of this so to try i first made the table script so that i can play with it but i was not able to get the correct answer so i thought of posting it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will join the tables and decide the rank based on marks and partition them via subjects

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT name,
        subject,
        marks,
        row_number() over (partition BY subject order by marks DESC) rank
    FROM student
    JOIN marks
    ON  student.roll_no = marks.roll_no
    )
WHERE rank <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with  cte as
(
   select S.Roll_no,S.Name,m.Subject,m.Marks, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by m.subject order by s.Roll_no)as RowID from Marks as m
   right outer join student as s
   on m.Roll_no=s.Roll_no
)select * from cte where RowID<=3
```